# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, html-table, append

I keep getting this error:

> "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression and instead saw an expression”

when trying to use Javascript to append my table.

Can anyone help me rectify this?

```
$('#lbUsers tbody').append('<tr><td>' + row.Number + '</td><td> ' + row.Name + '</td><td> ' + row.points + '</td><td>`' + row.stars + ' </td><td>' + row.Type '</td></tr>');
```

Full code:

```
$('#lbUsers').html('');

    db.transaction(function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM People;', [],

        function (transaction, result) {
            if (result !== null && result.rows !== null) {

                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                    `$('#lbUsers tbody').append('<tr><td>' + row.Number + '</td><td> ' + row.Name + '</td><td> ' + row.points + '</td><td>`' + row.stars + ' </td><td>' + row.Type '</td></tr>');
                }
            }
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler, nullHandler);

    return;

}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="lbUsers">
  <tbody>
     <th>Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Points</th><th>Stars</th><th>Type</th>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line:

```
`$('#lbUsers tbody').append('<tr><td>' + row.Number + '</td><td> ' + row.Name + '</td><td> ' + row.points + '</td><td>`' + row.stars + ' </td><td>' + row.Type '</td></tr>');
```

There should not be a leading ` character. Also, you are missing a concatenation operator ("+") after `row.Type`.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply. i have sorted those issues but still get the same error:

Comment: $('#lbUsers tbody').append('<tr><td>' + row.Number + '</td><td> ' + row.Name + '</td><td> ' + row.points + '</td><td>`' + row.stars + ' </td><td>' + row.Type + '</td></tr>');

Comment: Where are you getting this error? From the browser console? Also, what line is the error on?

Comment: the line of the error is $('#lbUsers tbody').append('<tr><td>' + row.Number + '</td><td> ' + row.Name + '</td><td> ' + row.points + '</td><td>`' + row.stars + ' </td><td>' + row.Type + '</td></tr>');

Comment: here is the html:   <table id="lbUsers">
  <tbody>
     <th>Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Points</th><th>Stars</th><th>Type</th>
  </tbody>
</table>

Comment: It will be easier to help if you make a JSFiddle or similar